# Is this a mutidimensional array that I can search for key-value?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Context: I am a novice programmer who has might lack a full 360 degree ability to ask the right questions.

Question:

I have an array `$sortablepast`:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#265 (6) { 
    ["Date"]=> string(25) "2014-12-28T08:15:00-08:00" 
    ["Id"]=> string(5) "78065" 
    ["HomeTeam"]=> string(7) "Man Utd" 
    ["AwayTeam"]=> string(9) "Leicester" 
    ["HomeGoals"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["AwayGoals"]=> string(1) "2" 
  } 

[1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#264 (6) { 
    ["Date"]=> string(25) "2014-12-28T08:15:00-08:00" 
    ["Id"]=> string(5) "78064" 
    ["HomeTeam"]=> string(8) "Man City" 
    ["AwayTeam"]=> string(7) "Burnley" 
    ["HomeGoals"]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["AwayGoals"]=> string(1) "3" 
  } 

[2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#266 (6) { 
    ["Date"]=> string(25) "2014-12-28T08:15:00-08:00" 
    ["Id"]=> string(5) "78085" 
    ["HomeTeam"]=> string(9) "Newcastle" 
    ["AwayTeam"]=> string(7) "Everton" 
    ["HomeGoals"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["AwayGoals"]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
  }
```

which is the result of a SimpleXMLobject converted into an array using:

```
<?php   $xmlpast = new SimpleXMLElement("xml_past_epl.xml", 0, TRUE);         
$sortablepast = array();
foreach($xmlpast->Match as $node) {
$sortablepast[] = $node;
}
?>
```

I have converted it into an array in order to use usort to sort it in alphabetical order.

I am trying to run an if statement so that if `"HomeTeam" = "Man Utd"` it will echo `"Man Utd are at home"`.

From the many answers to the question 'How do I search for a key-value pair in a multidimensional array' (including questions that I have asked) I have tried using `in_array`, `issset`, `array_map`, `array_filter` from answers on SO but none seem to work. I seem to be able access values where `key = '0', '1' or '2'` but not where `key = 'Date, 'Id'` etc.

I would therefore like to ask
a) Is this a multidimensional array, or in fact an array of objects? I don't have enough knowledge and experience to know whether the difference is significant
b) If it is not a multidimensional array do I need to convert it in some way or this there a way of searching it for a specific key-value pair (HomeTeam->Man Utd)?

I can give many example of what I have tried that hasn't worked but I thought it would be best to start by asking if there is something in the array that I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Everybody seems to jump on the "This is not a multidimensional array." bandwagon.

But this is exactly what you ask, so I'll try to answer your questions:

**a) Is this a multidimensional array, or in fact an array of objects? I don't have enough knowledge and experience to know whether the difference is significant**

As you noticed, it is in fact an array of object. You can see this because of

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#265 (6) { 
    ....
}
```

would have been

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(6) { 
    ....
}
```

if it the XMLObject was also converted to array, it would've been an multideminsional array.

Why is it an array with objects? 
Because you haven't converted the nodes them self.
This is what you do:

```
$sortablepast = array();
foreach($xmlpast->Match as $node) {
    $sortablepast[] = $node; // $node is not an array, all nodes within the XML are also SimpleXMLElements
}
```

**Is the difference significant?**

Well yes, but you don't need to order or do anything special within the match, so no need to convert it to an array as well.  So you just need the correct manipulation on the SimpleXMLElement(see below).

**b) If it is not a multidimensional array do I need to convert it in some way or this there a way of searching it for a specific key-value pair (HomeTeam->Man Utd)?**

No need you can still read the `SimpleXMLElement`.

For example:

```
foreach ($sortablepast as $match) {
   //$match is a SimpleXMLElement
   if ($match->HomeTeam == 'Man Utd') {
       echo 'Man Utd are at home';
   }
}
```

How to sort:

```
//Sort by HomeTeam alphabetically
usort($sortablepast, function($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->HomeTeam == $b->HomeTeam) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->HomeTeam < $b->HomeTeam) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: For info - I do need to make it into an array in order to sort alphabetically

Comment: You can still keep the Objects, and sort them within the flat array. Use `usort()`

Comment: Tim Dev - my bad. I had changed an obscure team to Man Utd in the question (for US readers) but not in my data! *embarassed emoticon*

Comment: ;)  I'll add a sorting mechanism example for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a multidimensional array. It is s **single dimensional array of objects**.

You have array with three elements, where every element is object of a `SimpleXMLElement` class.

```
echo $array[2]->HomeTeam;
echo $array[1]->Id;
```

etc.

I hope that [Reference (click!)](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) will help you

Comment: So what is the best way to check for 'if 'HomeTeam' = 'Man Utd' exists in this array'? Should I be using something like 'if ($array[wildcard] -> HomeTeam ==='Man Utd'?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: Can I ask what wildcard character(s) to use in this case?

Comment: It's array, so use keys. As you posted they are `0`, `1` and `2`. You can also iterate through every element using `foreach ($array as $row) { if ($row->HomeTeam === 'Man Utd') { ... } }`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have a array of objects rather than a multidimensional array. array size is 3, see first line of code.